# dev_appserver.py fails on startup

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

When starting the local development server with `dev_appserver.py` i get the following error.

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml
INFO     2017-07-03 06:51:09,662 devappserver2.py:116] Skipping SDK update check.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 369, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 176, in start
    configuration.modules[0].application_root, datastore_emulator_host)
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 524, in create_api_server
    appidentity_oauth_url=options.appidentity_oauth_url)
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 699, in setup_stubs
    oauth_url=appidentity_oauth_url)
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity_stub.py", line 198, in Create
    import six
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/six-1.9.0/six/__init__.py", line 825, in <module>
    from . import test_six
  File "/home/daniel/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/six-1.9.0/six/test_six.py", line 105, in <module>
    @py.test.mark.parametrize("item_name",
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parametrize'
```

Version:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 161.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.55
beta 2017.03.24
bq 2.0.24
core 2017.06.26
gcloud 
gsutil 4.26
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gcloud-sdk` component `app-engine-python==1.9.55` vendored `six==1.9.0` library seems to be dependent on `pytest`.

Issue is fixed by installing `pytest`

```
$ pip install pytest
```

See issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62980070

Answer (score 3):

This should only be an issue for users who have a pytest version < 2.2.0 installed locally, where the current version is 3.1.3. Users will not see this issue if either (a) they do not have pytest installed or (b) have pytest >= 2.2.0 installed. The @py.test.mark.parametrize() decorator at the end of the stack trace was introduced in 2.2.0.

We've submitted a patch that resolves this for users of pytest < 2.2.0 that will be available in the next App Engine SDK release. In the meantime, users can upgrade their pytest version locally and the issue should go away.

Comment: A local installation of pytest is not (and has not been) required for app-engine-python. 

The App Engine and Cloud SDKs include some third party libraries in the bundle. One of these libraries had a try/catch block around an import statement and some pytest logic that required pytest>=2.2.0.

The patch will make app-engine-python work with pytest<2.2.0.